# JQuery replace portion of text in <p> with an <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in my body :

```
<p>
    hello ok hello no
<p>

<p>
    ok hello ok ko 
<p>
```

I want to replace for each `<p>` the text 'ok' by `<img>` tag `<img src="ok.png" alt="good word"/>`

Is it possible to do this ?

Note : i must apply this function for others texts who can contain apostrophe and/or quote

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong It says that in the tags.

Comment: I know it's possible that this is a wacky constraint, but this should really be a server-side task.

Comment: What do you mean by "some other texts who can contain apostroph and/or quote?"

Comment: Pills : i mean for example replace this text : (i've blablabla, i've blalllll). replace i've by i have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each`:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\bok\b/g, '<img src="ok.png" alt="good word"/>')
})
```

I used `/\bok\b/` so that something like `token` won't match. `\b` means "word boundary."

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78pEB/1/).

Comment: thank's for ur solution, but i've this result : it remplace only first 'ok' of each <p> and it add breakline after replace

Comment: I try to change the word "ok" by others words as "how are you", i cant change it. If you have link of documentation for replace method, share it please, because of i found only documentation for replaceWith

Comment: @tchiko `replace is not jQuery, it is pure JS.

Comment: dont existe method in jquery for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('p').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/\bok/g,'<img src="ok.png" alt="good word" />');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AJa6N/1/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```
   var x=$('p').html();
    var n=x.replace("ok","<img src='ok.png' alt='good word'>"); 
    $('p').html(n);
```

Comment: this will replace all the `p`s with the text of the first `p`. Did you try it? You can try running it on this page and see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

try replaceWith - jquery

```
$( "<p>" ).replaceWith( '<img src="ok.png" alt="good word"/>');
$( "</p>" ).replaceWith( "" );
```

for more information read jquery documentation 
http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: The OP's trying to replace only the word "ok" with the image, and anyway this answer is wrong since `$('<p>')` creates a `p` element and the second one does absolutely nothing.