# Can I use CSS to replace a string of text with an image?

Tags: javascript, css, image, text, replace

I'm trying to edit my CSS so every time the text "admin" turns up it will replace that with an image, is this possible?

Edit: The CSS is for a subreddit, so I don't have the ability to edit the HTML!

Comment: Not with just CSS, but using Javascript it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917516/jquery-replace-portion-of-text-in-p-with-an-img

Comment: Why not just change the text to an `img` in the source itself?

Comment: Is this user-inputted text or static text?

Comment: Is javascript allowed? I agree with @Dreyden Long that you probably can't do it without JS, though I'd take a bit different approach than the answer in the link.

Comment: Well that sucks, thanks anyways!

Comment: do you have some example which element has the text "admin"? you can use attribute selectors in CSS which check for example the value and add a content: